# Mac bash script to organize downloaded file types

Tags: macos, bash

System: Mac OSX 10.6.8
Shell: Bash Shell (Terminal)

I'm trying to write a script that selectively organizes my Downloads folder.

Purpose:
- when the script is turned on, any files downloaded from a browser with a specific file type (ex: ".rar"), are saved in a subdirectory of Downloads (ex: "rar_downloads").
- does not effect current files in the Downloads directory
- when the script is turned off, downloaded files save normally to the Downloads directory.

I would appreciate any insight on how to write this. Thank you!

Comment: I wonder if AppleScript (Automator workflow?) wouldn’t be an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

A short outline: You want two time stamps, script-on and script-off, that define the temporal scope of your movements. Having the script work continuously is fairly hard because you'd need browser integration, so run it manually (or via a crontab).

Rough outline:

```
find Downloads -newer script-on -and -not -newer script-off | while read filename; do
     SUFFIX=`echo "$filename" | sed -n -e 's/.*\.\([^./]*\)$/\1/p'`;
     if [ -n "$SUFFIX" ]; then mv "$filename" "Downloads/${SUFFIX}_downloads"; fi
done
```

The sed expression in line 2 extracts the suffix, i.e. the terminal part of the filename after the last . in the last component, and prints no output if there is no suffix.

Comment: See http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-case-statement/ Example 3.  A case statement would help if you want to aggregate multiple file types in some folders (for example, to direct .jpeg, .jpg, .png to an ./images subfolder).  The "mkdir -p" command would also be helpful in either case to ensure your target subdirectory exists.  A very minor improvement for @thiton, too, is the use of "SUFFIX=${filename##*\.}" to capture a file extension.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt replies! Your code is a bit overwhelming, so I need to spend some time researching the commands used before I can understand what's going on here (not to mention regexp).